# Why my state does not change on click event with setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning React, and actually don't understand why my state does not change immediately when I press a button, with a click event. I mean, I created a state "test: false", but when I click on my button, I just want to change the state, so I used setState. But the console still shows me the "false" when I click for the first time.

[Here's a Codesandbox to illustrate my example.](https://codesandbox.io/embed/busy-lake-x7xsu?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      test: false
    };
    this.display.bind(this);
  }
  display() {
    this.setState({
      test: true
    });
    console.log(this.state.test)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={() => this.display()}>Click me!</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I also want to show  "Hello" if state is true and "Goodbye" if the state is false.
Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 2):

I have checked your code and found you are doing mistake there.

As setState() is async. One easy way to handle that is to give it a callback.
To print the state just after the `setState()`, you need to use the code as follows:

```
display() {
 this.setState({
  test: true
 }, console.log(this.state.test));
}
```

and about your updated query, you need to use ternary operator as follows:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={() => this.display()}>Click me!</button>
        {(this.state.test) ? <p>Hello</p> : <p>Bye</p>}

      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

make display an asynchronous function and you can also use es6 for your function deceleration not compulsory though

```
const display = async _ => {
    await this.setState({
      test: !this.state.test
    });
    await console.log(this.state.test)
  }
```

//now your button should appear like this

```
<button onClick={_ => display()}>Click me!</button>
```